# Maximum volume size of NTFS

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs

I was going through this [Microsoft's link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938432.aspx), and under NTFS section I have found the following information.

**NTFS:**  Maximum Volume size:  **power(2,64)** on disk format and **power(2,32)** on implemetation. What does this mean?

Secondly, on the same website it is mentioned 2TB as the maximum volume size of the NTFS file system. If that is the case, how are the new harddisks in the market of size>2TB accessed/formatted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2^32 is the number of allocation units (clusters) supported in the volume, which can be as large as 64KiB, meaning 256TiB volumes are the maximum supported NTFS volume size.

The note about 2TiB is specifically in relation to 512B sectors using MBR partition tables, which has the same quantity limit. They do not say that there, but that is what it means. That article was written 15 years ago, and a lot has changed. Drives now generally support 4K sectors (Advanced Format), and newer operating systems use GUID partition tables (GPT) which support much larger physical drives and distributed file storage devices, way past the 256TiB range.